# Optimizing mysql/postgresql for create and update

Tags: mysql, postgresql, select, rdbms

As far as I know most of the RDBMS packages are built keeping in mind 99% of the queries will be select queries. However, I am in a situation where we have at least 50 % of the queries as create/update queries. Since we also need persistence, we can not go for NoSQL solutions. Essentially, whenever there is an update it should be immediately stored permanently. So, I was wondering if the performance with MySQL will be hampered because of that. Our current MySQL engine is InnoDb. Is any other MySQL engine more preferable? I plan to use Amazon RDS so my focus is MySQL; but just out of curiousity I would like to know if postgresql can help in this.

N.B. - Just to give an idea of the scale, we are talking about create/update queries on tables with at least a million entries within a couple of months of going into production.

Comment: Partition your tables as much as you can, and don't allow to grow to much. Scale your tables from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your working set fits in memory, your inserts and updates will tend to be quite fast. Partitioning can help here, as others have mentioned.  Most NoSQL solutions have persistence so you shouldn't exclude them outright.  Cassandra has a storage model specifically tuned for writes and might be worth a look.

If you go with MySQL, there are tuning parameters to trade some durability for insert performance, and various other hardware and software settings:

https://serverfault.com/questions/118504/how-to-improve-mysql-insert-and-update-performance

You can probably expect around 100 inserts / sec using full durability on standard disks.  If that's not going to cut it, setup benchmarks and start tweaking parameters or get ready for some re-architecting.  Benchmark testing is important using realistic amounts of data in your tables. It's much better to find a problem now than to discover it 6 months down the road when your tables start to fill in.  Synthetic data is fine, just make sure the indexed fields are distributed similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Having as few as possible indexes increases speed of inserts and updates, because all indexes have to get updated when inserting/updating rows to the tables.
But of course, keep in mind that some indexes might increase your updates as weel.

Comment: For UPDATEs not all indexes have to be updated. Only those that contain columns that have been changed (at least for Postgres). And an index can speed up an UPDATE as well (if the WHERE condition can make use of the index)

Comment: Yes, speeding up UPDATES by indexes was what I ment with my second sentence. Was a bit misunderstandable.